# Grails - Websphere - No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined

Tags: grails, spring-security

**My Grails application is up and running in my localhost. However, when I try to deploy it on Websphere, I am getting the following error.**

*Error Message: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [springSecurityFilterChain]: could not be initialized
Error Code: 500
Target Servlet: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor
Error Stack: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined 
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) 
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1114) 
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:279) 
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198) 
     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1121) 
     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:323) 
     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235) 
     at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:194) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:145) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager._loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:600) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:507) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterInstanceWrapper(WebAppFilterManager.java:312) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterChain(WebAppFilterManager.java:385) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:924) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3763) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:976) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:277) 
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214) 
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113) 
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905) 
     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1700)*

Here's my Web.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
     metadata-complete="true"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<display-name>/@grails.project.key@</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>@grails.project.key@</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>characterEncodingFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>

</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Grails dispatcher servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>grails</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>dispatchOptionsRequest</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>

<!-- The Groovy Server Pages servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>gsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPagesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>gsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.gsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <!-- 30 minutes -->
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<welcome-file-list>
    <!--
    The order of the welcome pages is important.  JBoss deployment will
    break if index.gsp is first in the list.
    -->
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.gsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**I tried looking at the various solutions posted here before, but I am unable to make this work. Also, I am not sure where the other .xml files are present in the Grails project structure.**

Comment: Did you find solution to the above problem?I have issues deploying grails+spring security to websphere as well

Answer (score 1):

You won't find many xml files in a Grails app, pretty much just web.xml (and this is going away in Grails 3 since servlet 3.0 lets you do everything programmatically), and `web-app/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml` and `web-app/WEB-INF/sitemesh.xml`. Installed plugins also have `plugin.xml` files. Most everything is configured with code.

You don't say whether you're using the [spring-security-core plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) or wiring things up yourself, but it doesn't look like you're doing either one. If you were using the plugin, it would have added itself to web.xml, and if you were doing things yourself, you would have. This isn't affected by running in WebSphere or a proper server, since web.xml is generated when the war file is built, so while WebSphere may introduce further weirdness, it's not the bad guy this time.

Try running `grails clean` and `grails compile` before rebuilding and redeploying.

Is it possible that it's your build process? Do you just build a war with `grails war`?